# Как убрать горизонтальную прокрутку на сайте или найти виновника проблемы?

Tags: html, css, site

Пробывал смотреть через chrome (правой кнопкой/посмотреть код), открывал с телефона адаптированую мобильную версию, проблему невозможно найти..

Cправа вертикально сайта есть белый участок (вдоль всего сайта), куда каким-то образом начал прокручиваться сайт по-горизонатали.

Как найти это зло? Всё уже перелопатил.. Ресурс: [garanttransauto.ru/qw/](http://garanttransauto.ru/qw/)
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема находится в блоке `.call`, а именно блок `.col-md-12`. Вы вкладываете колонку в колонку